# How to store non-secret data in aries agent storage using ACA-Py framework?

Tags: python, shell, hyperledger-indy

I want to store some data in Aries Agent Storage apart from  DIDs, keys, ledger objects and credentials. This [aries-rfcs](https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-rfcs/tree/master/concepts/0050-wallets#tags-and-queries) has something in this regard.

I got some direction from Hyperledger rocket chat that we can use non-secret APIs to store any data. But I don't know how to use it as I am quite new to python and Aries and Indy projects.

I am trying [Alice-Faber demo](https://github.com/cloudcompass/ToIPLabs/blob/master/docs/LFS173x/AliceGetsCredential.md). As per my understanding till now if I able to call the functions of this [file](https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-cloudagent-python/blob/master/aries_cloudagent/storage/basic.py) from the [Faber](https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-cloudagent-python/blob/master/demo/runners/faber.py) or [Alice](https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-cloudagent-python/blob/master/demo/runners/alice.py) files then I can store data successfully. But don't know how to do this.